# How to setup local laravel with containered mysql service

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-8

i know there are tons of answer for question like these, but i still not able to connect.
I have a local clean installation of laravel 8 and a docker container running mysql. I am able to access the container and manage it, but when run migrate got "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known". Some advice will be nice, thx.

My .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=birdboard
DB_USERNAME=pedro
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mysql:
    build: phpdocker/mysql57
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - "3306"
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

# Names our volume
volumes:
  mysql:
```

Comment: If your application isn't in a container, then it needs to connect to the host's DNS name (or `localhost` if it's on the same system as the container) and the first `ports:` number.  You can delete `expose:` (which doesn't do anything at all) and `container_name:` (Compose provides a sensible default).

Comment: Ty David, it worked. For the record, in Laravel, DNS name should be `127.0.0.1` for `localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your .env file is  wrong

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=birdboard 
DB_USERNAME=pedro 
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Comment: OR  /etc/host add line

127.0.0.1 mysql